Change the PayPal Checkout from Sandbox to Production
I integrated on a site the payment button.
I ran all the tests in Sandbox without any problems.
The button is the standard one that is generated to which I added javascript code to change the value and the return page
<script src="https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=xxxxu_Te57qBkvhtttKnIt1CEyyyyaIgtJZwYCxORrisrvuX6AXKFMilTZZ_Y1W1oNSk&vault=true&currency=EUR&locale=it_IT"></script>
<div style="max-width:550px; display: inline-block;">
  <div id="paypal-button-container"></div>
</div>
<script>
paypal.Buttons({
  createOrder: function(data, actions) {
    // This function sets up the details of the transaction, including the amount and line item details.
    return actions.order.create({
      purchase_units: [{
        amount: {
          currencyCode: "EUR",
          value: '10',
        },
      }],
      style: {
        disableMaxWidth: true
      },
      application_context: {
        shipping_preference: 'NO_SHIPPING'
      }
    });
  },
  onApprove: function(data, actions) {
    // This function captures the funds from the transaction.
    return actions.order.capture().then(details => {
      // This function shows a transaction success message to your buyer.
      //  alert('Transaction completed by ' + details.payer.name.given_name);
      document.getElementById('loader').style.display = 'none'; // Nasconde il loader
      document.getElementById('redirectMessage').style.display = 'block'; // Mostra il messaggio di redirect
      setTimeout(function() {
        // Effettua il redirect dopo 5 secondi
        window.location.href = 'return.asp';
      }, 5000);
    });
  },
  onCancel: function(data) {
    console.log('Pagamento annullato:', data);
    document.getElementById('errorPay').innerHTML = 'Pagamento annullato.';
    document.getElementById('errorPay').style.display = 'block';
  },
  onError: function(err) {
    console.error('Errore durante il pagamento:', err);
    // Accesso al codice e al messaggio di errore specifico
    var errorCode = err.code;
    var errorMessage = err.message;
    alert(errorCode)
    switch (errorCode) {
      case 'CHECKOUT__PAYMENT_FAILED':
        document.getElementById('errorPay').innerHTML = 'Pagamento fallito. Si prega di riprovare.';
        document.getElementById('errorPay').style.display = 'block';
        break;
      case 'CHECKOUT__PAYMENT_CANCELED':
        document.getElementById('errorPay').innerHTML = 'Pagamento annullato.';
        document.getElementById('errorPay').style.display = 'block';
        break;
      default:
        document.getElementById('errorPay').innerHTML = 'Si è verificato un errore durante il pagamento: ' + errorMessage;
        document.getElementById('errorPay').style.display = 'block';
    }
  }
}).render('#paypal-button-container');
</script>

what I changed in the transition from sandbox to real is only the client-id
But I can't get the button to work and in the broswer console I have these error messages

{"err": "Error: /v2/checkout/orders returned status 403 (Corr ID:f8372090db9a9).\n\n{"name":"NOT_AUTHORIZED","details":[{"issue":"PERMISSION_DENIED","description":"You do not have permission to access or perform operations on this resource."}],"message":"Authorization failed due to insufficient permissions.","debug_id":"f8372090db9a9","links":[{"href":"https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/orders/v2/#error-PERMISSION_DENIED","rel":"information_link"}]}\n


actions.order.create( and actions.order.capture( are deprecated and should not be used for any new integration, even if you can get them to work communications have already started being sent that support will be sunset and removed in the future.
Instead, use a backend to create and capture orders with the v2/checkout/orders API. See the standard integration guide for examples in node.js, though its two routes (one to create, one to capture) can of course be implemented in any language/environment.

Thanks, but I don't understand how it is possible that a code taken from the documentation now doesn't work. in the sandbox it works and only by changing the idclient it doesn't work. all the sites that have the old code how do they work?

It's deprecated code, no longer supported by PayPal for new integrations, no longer available in its documentation. Your specific problem may be caused by something else, try creating a new live app or something to troubleshoot, but you should not be using this code without a backend.

application_context is also a deprecated parameter for the orders create request, in addition to creating via API backend should use the new payment_source.paypal.experience_context.shipping_preference object https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/orders/v2/#orders_create!path=payment_source/paypal/experience_context/shipping_preference&t=request
